# How to only increase quantity in database if the product is already entered to the database?

Tags: java, sql, swing, jdbc

I have created a food ordering system, which has 5 different JFrames having their own categories, such as Meal, fast-food, Appetizers, Beverages. Each category has popups for each food which is another JFrame. This is where, when customer selects the needed meals, it will be added to the database.

I have created a query for the database where, on selection of different meals from popup menu, those items will be entered into the database. This is working perfectly.

However, I want to update only the quantity if the product description exists. For example, if Cheese burger is available in database, I want to only increase quantity. How can I do this?

```
    public void  InsertOrderDetails(){
         String Insert;
         String Update;
         int i = Integer.parseInt(DBqty);
         BigDecimal Totals=new BigDecimal(DBtotalPrice);
         BigDecimal TotalValue=new BigDecimal(Total);
            try
            {    
             //Opening database for connection
            conn = DriverManager.getConnection(connectionUrl, username, Pass);
            Statement st=conn.createStatement();
            String sql="SELECT * FROM SALESORDER WHERE ProductDescription ='" + ProductDescription +"'";
            ResultSet rs=st.executeQuery(sql);
            if(rs.next()){
            int quan =i+ qty;
            BigDecimal totaly = Totals.add(TotalValue);
             Update="UPDATE SALESORDER SET Quantity=? ,TotalPrice=? WHERE ProductDescription ='" + ProductDescription +"'";
             PreparedStatement pstmt = conn.prepareStatement(Update);
             pstmt.setInt(1, quan);
             pstmt.setBigDecimal(2, totaly);
             pstmt.executeUpdate();
             pstmt.close();
             JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"Sucessfully Added to plate");
            }
            
           else{   
            
             Insert="INSERT INTO SalesOrder (CustID,ProductDescription,Quantity,TotalPrice) VALUES (?,?,?,?)";
             PreparedStatement pstmt = conn.prepareStatement(Insert);
             pstmt.setInt(1,CustID);
             pstmt.setString(2, ProductDescription);
             pstmt.setInt(3, qty);
             pstmt.setBigDecimal(4, TotalValue);
             pstmt.executeUpdate();
             pstmt.close();
             JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"Sucessfully Added to plate");
            }
            }
            catch(SQLException e){
                   JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"Something went wrong\n");
                 e.printStackTrace();
      
        }
            finally{
                try {
                    
                    conn.close();
                } catch (SQLException ex) {
                    Logger.getLogger(POPUP_Message_FriedRice.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
                }} 
       }
```

Comment: `statement.executeUpdate` returns an `int` as result which is the number of affected rows. You can use it to know whether any record is update or not.

Comment: By the way if you are using a `PreparedStatement` don't concat the product description, use the `?` for the parameter and bind it, this way you must omit the single quotes. So the query will be: `update SALESORDER set Quantity = ?, TotalPrice = ? where ProductDescription = ?`

Comment: Besides that you can do something like `update SALESORDER set Quantity = Quantity + ?, TotalPrice = TotalPrice + ? where ProductDescription = ?`, so you just increase the numbers, and no need to retrieve it before increasing it.

Comment: So I make it an answer and you accept it.

Answer (score 1):

`Statement.executeUpdate` returns an `int` which is the number of affected rows, you can understand whether records existed or not using this field.

So your code become something like:

```
public static final String UPDATE_QUERY = "UPDATE SALESORDER SET Quantity = Quantity + ?, TotalPrice = TotalPrice + ? WHERE ProductDescription = ? and CustId = ?";
public static final String INSERT_STATEMENT = "INSERT INTO SalesOrder (CustID,ProductDescription,Quantity,TotalPrice) VALUES (?,?,?,?)";

public void InsertOrderDetails() {
    try (Connection connection = DriverManager.getConnection(connectionUrl, username, password)) {
        //Opening database for connection
        int affectedRows;
        try (PreparedStatement updateStatement = connection.prepareStatement(UPDATE_QUERY)) {
            updateStatement.setInt(1, quantity);
            updateStatement.setBigDecimal(2, itemPrice);
            updateStatement.setString(3, productDescription);
            updateStatement.setInt(4, customerId);

            affectedRows = updateStatement.executeUpdate();
        }

        if (affectedRows > 0) {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Sucessfully Added to plate");
        } else {
            try (PreparedStatement insertStatement = connection.prepareStatement(INSERT_STATEMENT)) {
                insertStatement.setInt(1, customerId);
                insertStatement.setString(2, productDescription);
                insertStatement.setInt(3, quantity);
                insertStatement.setBigDecimal(4, itemPrice);
                insertStatement.executeUpdate();
            }

            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Sucessfully Added to plate");
        }
    } catch (SQLException e) {
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Something went wrong\n");
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

I am using Java 7 **try with resource** here to remove some duplicate code.

Comment: Thanks , its working fine , thats for helping me reduce code redudancy ,

Answer (score 0):

```
    public void  InsertOrderDetails(){
     String Insert;
     String Update;
     BigDecimal TotalValue=new BigDecimal(Total);
        try
        {    
         //Opening database for connection
        conn = DriverManager.getConnection(connectionUrl, username, Pass);
        Statement st=conn.createStatement();
        String sql="SELECT * FROM SALESORDER WHERE ProductDescription ='" + ProductDescription +"'";
        ResultSet rs=st.executeQuery(sql);
        if(rs.next()){
         Update="update SALESORDER set Quantity = Quantity + ?, TotalPrice = TotalPrice + ? where ProductDescription = ?";
         PreparedStatement pstmt = conn.prepareStatement(Update);
         pstmt.setInt(1,qty);
         pstmt.setBigDecimal(2,TotalValue);
         pstmt.setString(3,ProductDescription);
         pstmt.executeUpdate();
         pstmt.close();
         JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"Sucessfully Added to plate");
        }
        
       else{   
        
         Insert="INSERT INTO SalesOrder (CustID,ProductDescription,Quantity,TotalPrice) VALUES (?,?,?,?)";
         PreparedStatement pstmt = conn.prepareStatement(Insert);
         pstmt.setInt(1,CustID);
         pstmt.setString(2, ProductDescription);
         pstmt.setInt(3, qty);
         pstmt.setBigDecimal(4, TotalValue);
         pstmt.executeUpdate();
         pstmt.close();
         JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"Sucessfully Added to plate");
        }
        }
        catch(SQLException e){
               JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"Something went wrong\n");
             e.printStackTrace();
  
    }
        finally{
            try {
                
                conn.close();
            } catch (SQLException ex) {
                Logger.getLogger(POPUP_Message_FriedRice.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
            }} 
   }
```